# How to link a Cocoa Touch Static Library to a MonoTouch project?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, linker, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

**I have created a Cocoa Touch Static Library using Xcode 4 and I want to use it in a MonoTouch project. How do I proceed?**

Here is the content of my Static Library :

MyClass.h
[image: header]

MyClass.m
[image: implementation]

---

I built using "Build For Archiving" after following [THIS BLOG POST](http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.ca/2012/01/how-to-use-objective-c-library-in.html) and I took the libMyLib.a it generated and added it to a new MonoTouch Binding Project.
[image: binding project]

Then I replaced the content of libMyLib.linkwith.cs, because [THIS BLOG POST](http://dantes-andreea.blogspot.ca/2012/01/how-to-use-objective-c-library-in.html) said so.

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libMyLib.a", LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks="CoreGraphics QuartzCore UIKit")]
```

Then I added this to ApiDefinition.cs
[image]

I left StructsAndEnums.cs empty.

---

Then I built with Release and took the dll from the bin folder and added it to the root of a MonoTouch iPad project, and added it to the references.

Then, after following the instructions in [THIS ARTICLE](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Linking_the_Dependencies), I set the mtouch arguments to this

```
-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lMyLib -force_load -ObjC"
```

Then I tried to run the project and I got this error in the Build Output

> error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review user flags provided to gcc: "-L/Users/herpderp/Projects/TestProject/TestProject" "-lMyLib" -force_load "/Users/herpderp/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/libMyLib.a" "-L/Users/herpderp/Projects/TestProject/TestProject" "-lMyLib" "-force_load" "-ObjC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This directory contains a full sample showing various ways of integrating Objective-C libraries with MonoTouch:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/BindingSample

Comment: that helped, i just modified the sample project to fit my needs

Answer (score 1):

The error message for **MT5201** tells you there was an error while doing the native link step. That's 100% sure. The second part ask to to review your `gcc_flags`, which is the most common reason, for the failure. However it's **not** 100% sure this is the issue. When you seek help you should always paste the lines above any error (as they might be useful).

The error is *likely* about the duplication of the options given to the native linker. This occurs because you did supplied them twice (i.e. in your binding project and in your main project).

From the [Binding Objective-C Types](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types#Linking_the_Dependencies) article you linked:

> Or you can take advantage of the assembly-level LinkWithAttribute, that you can embed in your contract files...

It means the **additional mtouch arguments** are **not** needed with you use `LinkWith` attribute. Since you're using this way (the best one :-) to bind your static library you can skip this step (from your main project).

By doing so you do yourself (and anyone using your library) a favor since they are less risky to get out-of-sync (e.g. library update or different build configuration).

Comment: When I remove the additional mtouch arguments, nothing works. I can call MyClass.Test("str") from my binding, but nothing happens, and I have no idea what is wrong with my binding. Could it be related to missing compiler flags from my xcode project? or because I selected "Build For Archiving" when I built my static library?

Comment: **Nothing works** well it builds and it did not before (so I'd call this progress ;-). Now why ? Hard to say. Is the `.a` a fat library that's usable from the simulator/device test app you're using it ?